# Is Leibnizian calculus embeddable in first order logic?

Tags: mathematics, mathematicians

We just published an article making what we feel is a plausible case in favor of an affirmative answer in *Foundations of Science*, see preprint [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/1605.03501). The basic argument is that while such a requirement may seem very limitative, such an embedding seems possible with a small number of additional ingredients like a black box for returing the sum of a series, and I was curious how well-supported this appears and if there are aspects that may have been overlooked.

Crosslisted at [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1791361).

Comment: Cross-posting creates problems for moderators and is discouraged http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu This also looks like an invitation to discuss a paper more than an answerable question for SE. But this kind is sufficiently unusual, so I am not sure how people might feel.  Perhaps you could change "how convincing" to something less opinion based, and "aspects that may have been overlooked" to something more specific.

Comment: @Conifold, I got rid of the "convincing" but I am not sure what to do about the aspects.  If I knew which aspects we overlooked I wouldn't have overlooked them :-) Given Leibniz's vast oeuvre it is surely possible that we overlooked a relevant aspect that doesn't lend itself easily to first order formalisation. I am pretty sure nobody found a proof of the extreme value theorem there, though.

Comment: I don't see how this is really a question for a site on the History of Science and Mathematics. It is simply a technical math question, no more and no less.

Comment: @KCd, the question requires a certain amount of expertise in the work of Leibniz, which not all technical mathematicians possess.

Comment: I'd argue that to do Leibnizian (and Eulerian, and Lagrangian etc.) calculus, the formalisation of "$y$ is a function *of* $x$" is required first. I asked about that [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/307947) and although no one stated it explicitly, I think the answer is no, this is no directly formalisable in first order logic.